# how to enable clean urls in drupal 8.5.0

Tags: drupal, installation

[image]

Please help me out how to fix CLEAN URLS warning in drupal 8.5.0

Answer (score 3):

Most likely .htaccess file usage is disabled for your site. Check for webserver settings file. Since you are running apache server it should be in:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

So there you should find config file for your site (it can happen that your site is using default config!), change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` , add  `allow from all` if it's missing (all inside `directory` tag) and then restart apache with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

For more detailed instructions check out this post:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles